# What is BlueFoot in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

What is bluefoot in Magento2 enterprise edition and how to use this.

Please suggest me how we can customize element.

Answer (score 1):

BlueFoot is a powerful set of tools to help you create and manage content on your Magento store, everything from product descriptions through to blogs.

Working alongside merchants, retailers, agencies and developers BlueFoot has been created with one aim, empower Magento users to create fantastic content quickly and easily without the need for other platforms or systems.

BlueFoot gives you the power to design and create web pages the way you want them.

**Refer this link for more informatiom:**

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-acquires-technology-behind-bluefoot-cms-page-builder

Answer (score 0):

Bluefoot is a page builder available in Magento 2 Enterprise Edition. It is designed to make it easier for merchants to create and manage store content. It includes a drag-and-drop interface for creating content blocks and pages and an easy-to-use WYSIWYG editor.

Bluefoot also allows merchants to customize their content with widgets and extensions. It is designed to be mobile-friendly and integrates with other Magento 2 Enterprise features, such as customer segmentation and product catalogs. To use Bluefoot, merchants must purchase the Magento 2 Enterprise Edition.